# How to remove the download tab still appearing on videos after uninstalling Wondershare AllMyTube

Tags: data-transfer, menu-bar, safari-extensions, chrome-extensions

I've downloaded and installed Wondershare AllMyTube for Mac for a quick look to see if it was any good. Then I decided that I didn't want it and uninstalled it.

However on all website videos (news) when I go to play the video it shows a download bar just above the video and if I click it, it just shows an unable to find link page via finder. I have tried all ways to get rid of this download facility but can't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To properly uninstall Wondershare AllMyTube for Mac you have to remove additionally the following files or folders - besides the app itself:

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/MediaDownloadKit
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/Wondershare AllMyTube
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/Safari/Extensions/AllMyTube.safariextz
```

If you have no other Wondershare apps you may also remove:

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/wondershare
```

with [user]: your user name

If you usually use Chrome check the Chrome extensions from inside Google Chrome and delete the Wondershare AllMyTube extension. In Firefox check the Add-ons and delete the Wondershare AllMyTube add-on.

Usually the user's Library folder is invisible. To open it use in the Finder's menubar Go -> "Go to Folder..." (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and enter `~/Library`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however none of those files are listed within there?

Comment: Bill, the Library folder doesn't show in the Finder...  you'll likely need to drop to the Terminal in order to access the folder you are looking for, or use the "go to folder" option in Finder.